# WCF tracing in Azure production

Tags: wcf, azure, trace

How do I set WCF tracing in Azure (production environment) so that I'll have logging of all WCF errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you use Windows Azure Diagnostics for this purpose? Once it is properly configured, your trace logs will be available in a Windows Azure Storage account that you have specified in your code. More information about Windows Azure Diagnostics can be found here: https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/diagnostics/.

Answer (score 0):

Just like Guarav said, you can simply use the Azure diagnostics to log all errors to your storage account (there's a good read in the MSDN Magazine: [Take Control of Logging and Tracing in Windows Azure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff714589.aspx)).

Now I personally don't like the 'flat' logging when working with WCF. I find it very important to be able to trace through activities. That's why for all Azure projects where I use WCF I don't use the normal diagnostics.

I use a trick documented by [Christian Weyer](http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cweyer/2010/12/writing-trace-data-to-your-beloved-svclog-files-in-windows-azure-aka-xmlwritertracelistener-in-the-cloud.html) where I log to a classic *.svclog file and have those files shipped to my storage account. Then I use the CloudBerry Storage Explorer to simply view those logs that include the activites. This is possible by creating a custom XmlWriterTraceListener that writes to a local resource which is shipped to your storage account.