# Service Fabric connecting to secure clusters with Wcf clients

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, azure-service-fabric

I cannot establish a Wcf connection to a secure fabric cluster. After gathering the logs thanks to sotn's recommendation, the issue is a simple TCP endpoint not found exception (TCP code 10060). The endpoint most certainly exists (fabric is resolving it, I'm only providing the named service) and when I check the cluster settings the port is in fact open. Therefore, I think something must be going on with security. However, using the same credentials I can create a fabric client to the cluster.

The cluster is secured with x509 certs. I am having trying to create a wcf client which can be used from a VM outside of the cluster where the Wcf service is deployed. I followed the guides [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-wcf) for setting up the service and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-connect-to-secure-cluster).

```
string serverCertThumb = "xxx";
string clientCertThumg = "xxx";
string commonName = "mycluster.southcentralus.cloudapp.azure.com";
string connection = " mycluster.southcentralus.cloudapp.azure.com:19000";

var xc = GetCredentials(clientCertThumg, serverCertThumb, commonName);
var resolver = new ServicePartitionResolver(xc, connection);
var myFactory = new WcfCommunicationClientFactory<IData>(WcfUtility.CreateTcpListenerBinding(), null,
    resolver, null, null);
var client = myFactory.CreateClient(new System.Uri("fabric:/MyServicePath"));

static X509Credentials GetCredentials(string clientCertThumb, string serverCertThumb, string name)
{
    X509Credentials xc = new X509Credentials();
    xc.StoreLocation = StoreLocation.CurrentUser;
    xc.StoreName = "My";
    xc.FindType = X509FindType.FindByThumbprint;
    xc.FindValue = clientCertThumb;
    xc.RemoteCommonNames.Add(name);
    xc.RemoteCertThumbprints.Add(serverCertThumb);
    xc.ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign;
    return xc;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I added some clarification. When I invoke eg client.Channel.MyMethod() the connection opens (or tries to) and then hangs indefinitely. I don't get a timeout or an exception. I can't seem to figure out the problem and am looking for any advice.

Comment: did you try wcf tracing in both server and client?

Comment: I might have a misunderstanding, but since the underlying VMs service fabric is running on are abstracted away, the service won't know where to log trace files to (or at least I won't know how to find them since I don't know what machine is running the service)

Comment: Check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11608024/wcf-tracing-in-azure-production) or google for Azure WCF Tracing. Otherwise; it's harder to understand what's going on..

Comment: Yes I don't think that applies. That was my comment above. I could be wrong, but it's not like there is a server I can log on to and grab an output log file

Comment: It will not log to the server but will log to your Azure Storage.

Comment: Looks like there is an option here to integrate the two https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-diagnostic-collect-logs-without-an-agent